# Text and checkbox alignment

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code that produces the following output:

```
            <span><b>System Type</b></span>

            <img src="~/Content/images/blank_img.png" alt="blank" />

            <input type="checkbox" class="switch hidden" id="myswitch@(i)"
                   data-on-text="Active"
                   data-off-text="Inactive" />
```

Output:

[image]

Note that:

```
 <img src="~/Content/images/blank_img.png" alt="blank" />
```

is just a white image.

My goal is to have the text ("System Type") aligned with Checkbox WITHOUT the use of the blank_img.png image. If I comment out the reference to the image file, I get the following:

[image]

How do I get the same alignment without the use of a blank image which does the trick..

Comment: Either `line-height` or `vertical-align` are possible solutions depending on your layout, could you show your current CSS?

Comment: It seems that some kind of advanced control is inserted instead of the simple checkbox element. Without knowing what that advanced control is, or how it is styled, I don't see how we could really answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `display: inline-block` on both elements and:

```
line-height: height of the switch;
vertical-align: middle;
```

in the "System Type" span.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a `<div>` container that contains the System Type text and the Checkbox button.